# Specifying Image Button image URL in code behind of asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while now, because the ID of the Image Button I created ('titanBtn') is not recognised in my code behind file. Which would allow me to simply write 'titanBtn.ImageUrl =" but alas, the code behind says it doesn't exist.

All I am trying to do with this code, is take a string read from the Db, that specifies the filename of the image (the appropriate images are named after the element type of each object), and puts this in a concatenated string that specifies the ImageUrl.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="titanRptr" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr class="tr1">
                <td><%# Eval("TitanName") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="titanBtn" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" OnClick="titanBtn_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>Level: <%# Eval("char_lvl")%>
                    <br />
                    Step: <%# Eval("step")%>
                    <br />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code behind

```
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("getElement", conn))
                    {
                        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", titanElement);
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2))
                        {
                            SqlDataReader reader;
                            conn.Open();
                            reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                titanImage = Convert.ToString(reader["Element"]);
                                titanBtn.ImageUrl = "images/" + titanImage+ ".gif"; //"The name 'titanBtn' does not exist in the current context"
                                titanRptr

                            }
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the ImageButton of each item in the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void titanRptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton titanBtn = e.Item.FindControl("titanBtn") as ImageButton;
    ...
}
```

However, if you could get the `Element` data directly in the data source of the repeater, you could do this in the markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="titanBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "images/" + Eval("Element") + ".gif" %>' ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageButton is inside a Repeater so cannot be accessed by ID.

However, you can use `FindControl` to get this control and there are (at least) two ways you can go about this.

On your Repeater you can attach an event to the ItemDataBound (`<asp:Repeater ID="titanRptr" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="titanRptr_ItemDataBound">`) and then do tasks for each row of the repeater as it is data bound. For example...

```
protected virtual void titanRptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        ImageButton titanBtn = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("titanBtn");
        //etc etc
        //get any values you need (eg)
        int something = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "something");
```

Or you can loop through the repeater after it has been databound and access each row and find the control, eg...

```
foreach (RepeaterItem row in titanRptr.Items)
{
    ImageButton titanBtn = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("titanBtn");
    //etc etc

}
```